# Display custom sync adapter as an option when adding contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am writing a custom sync adapter following the example in the SDK sample, and things seem to be working well. I can sync back contacts from my server and have them appear in the Contacts app.

However, I am unable to add a contact directly to my server. Specifically, I want my sync adapter to appear as an option in the Spinner on the add contact screen, in addition to Google and Corporate, as shown in the screenshot. I couldn't find anything on the interwebs that talks about this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. Turns out the contacts.xml file defining a `ContactsAccountType` that ships with the SDK sample is pretty bare bones. Fleshing it out a little makes my sync adapter appear in the Spinner ([beginning with Android 4.0.3 according to this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5988#c49)).

A sample showing all available fields is available [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.4_r1.2/packages/apps/Contacts/tests/res/xml/test_basic_contacts.xml/?v=source). I have copied it below for reference:

```
<ContactsAccountType
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<EditSchema
    >
    <!--
        Name:
        - maxOccurs must be 1
        - No types.

        - Currently all the supportsXxx attributes must be true, but here's the plan for the
          future:
          (There's some hardcoded assumptions in the contact editor, which is one reason
          for the above restriction)

            - "Family name" and "Given name" must be supported.
                - All sync adapters must support structured name. "display name only" is not
                  supported.
                  -> Supporting this would require relatively large changes to
                     the contact editor.

            - Fields are decided from the attributes:
                StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME         if supportsDisplayName == true
                StructuredName.PREFIX               if supportsPrefix == true
                StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME          (always)
                StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME          if supportsPrefix == true
                StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME           (always)
                StructuredName.SUFFIX               if supportsSuffix == true
                StructuredName.PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME if supportsPhoneticFamilyName == true
                StructuredName.PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME if supportsPhoneticMiddleName == true
                StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME  if supportsPhoneticGivenName == true

            - DataKind.PSEUDO_MIME_TYPE_DISPLAY_NAME  is always added.
            - DataKind.PSEUDO_MIME_TYPE_PHONETIC_NAME is added
              if any of supportsPhoneticXxx == true
    -->
    <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  Supports all. -->
    <DataKind kind="name"
        maxOccurs="1"
        supportsDisplayName="true"
        supportsPrefix="true"
        supportsMiddleName="true"
        supportsSuffix="true"
        supportsPhoneticFamilyName="true"
        supportsPhoneticMiddleName="true"
        supportsPhoneticGivenName="true"
        >
    </DataKind>

    <!-- Exchange definition.  No display-name, no phonetic-middle.
    <DataKind kind="name"
        supportsDisplayName="false"
        supportsPrefix="true"
        supportsMiddleName="true"
        supportsSuffix="true"
        supportsPhoneticFamilyName="true"
        supportsPhoneticMiddleName="false"
        supportsPhoneticGivenName ="true"
        >
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Photo:
        - maxOccurs must be 1
        - No types.
    -->
    <DataKind kind="photo" maxOccurs="1" />

    <!--
        Phone definition.
        - "is secondary?" is inferred from type.
    -->
    <!-- Fallback, Google definition.  -->
    <DataKind kind="phone" >
        <!-- Note: Google type doesn't have obsolete ones -->
        <Type type="mobile" />
        <Type type="home" />
        <Type type="work" />
        <Type type="fax_work" />
        <Type type="fax_home" />
        <Type type="pager" />
        <Type type="other" />
        <Type type="custom"/>
        <Type type="callback" />
        <Type type="car" />
        <Type type="company_main" />
        <Type type="isdn" />
        <Type type="main" />
        <Type type="other_fax" />
        <Type type="radio" />
        <Type type="telex" />
        <Type type="tty_tdd" />
        <Type type="work_mobile"/>
        <Type type="work_pager" />
        <Type type="assistant" />
        <Type type="mms" />
    </DataKind>

    <!-- Exchange definition.
    <DataKind kind="phone" >
        <Type type="home" maxOccurs="2" />
        <Type type="mobile" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="work" maxOccurs="2" />
        <Type type="fax_work" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="fax_home" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="pager" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="car" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="company_main" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="mms" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="radio" maxOccurs="1" />
        <Type type="assistant" maxOccurs="1" />
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Email
    -->
    <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  -->
    <DataKind kind="email" >
        <!-- Note: Google type doesn't have obsolete ones -->
        <Type type="home" />
        <Type type="work" />
        <Type type="other" />
        <Type type="mobile" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>

    <!--
        Exchange definition.
        - Same definition as "fallback" except for maxOccurs=3
    <DataKind kind="email" maxOccurs="3" >
        <Type type="home" />
        <Type type="work" />
        <Type type="other" />
        <Type type="mobile" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Nickname
        - maxOccurs must be 1
        - No types.
    -->
    <DataKind kind="nickname" maxOccurs="1" />

    <!--
        Im:
         - The TYPE column always stores Im.TYPE_OTHER (defaultValues is always set)
         - The user-selected type is stored in Im.PROTOCOL
    -->
    <!-- Fallback, Google definition.  -->
    <DataKind kind="im" >
        <Type type="aim" />
        <Type type="msn" />
        <Type type="yahoo" />
        <Type type="skype" />
        <Type type="qq" />
        <Type type="google_talk" />
        <Type type="icq" />
        <Type type="jabber" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>

    <!-- Exchange definition.
    <DataKind kind="im" maxOccurs="3" >
        <Type type="aim" />
        <Type type="msn" />
        <Type type="yahoo" />
        <Type type="skype" />
        <Type type="qq" />
        <Type type="google_talk" />
        <Type type="icq" />
        <Type type="jabber" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Postal address.
    -->
    <!-- Fallback/Google definition.  Not structured. -->
    <DataKind kind="postal" needsStructured="false" >
        <Type type="home" />
        <Type type="work" />
        <Type type="other" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>

    <!-- Exchange definition.  Structured.
    <DataKind kind="postal" needsStructured="true" >
        <Type type="work" />
        <Type type="home" />
        <Type type="other" />
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Organization:
        - Fields are fixed: COMPANY, TITLE
        - maxOccurs must be 1
        - No types.
    -->
    <DataKind kind="organization" maxOccurs="1" />

    <!--
        Website:
        - No types.
    -->
    <DataKind kind="website" />

    <!--
        Below kinds have nothing configurable.
        - No types are supported.
        - maxOccurs must be 1
    -->
    <DataKind kind="sip_address" maxOccurs="1" />
    <DataKind kind="note" maxOccurs="1" />

    <!--
        Google/Exchange supports it, but fallback doesn't.
    <DataKind kind="group_membership" maxOccurs="1" />
    -->

    <!--
        Event
    -->
    <DataKind kind="event" dateWithTime="false">
        <Type type="birthday" maxOccurs="1" yearOptional="true" />
        <Type type="anniversary" />
        <Type type="other" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>

    <!--
        Exchange definition.  dateWithTime is needed only for Exchange.
    <DataKind kind="event" dateWithTime="true">
        <Type type="birthday" maxOccurs="1" />
    </DataKind>
    -->

    <!--
        Relationship
    -->
    <DataKind kind="relationship" >
        <Type type="assistant" />
        <Type type="brother" />
        <Type type="child" />
        <Type type="domestic_partner" />
        <Type type="father" />
        <Type type="friend" />
        <Type type="manager" />
        <Type type="mother" />
        <Type type="parent" />
        <Type type="partner" />
        <Type type="referred_by" />
        <Type type="relative" />
        <Type type="sister" />
        <Type type="spouse" />
        <Type type="custom" />
    </DataKind>
</EditSchema>
```