# AccountManager. Account type for contacts

Tags: android, contactscontract, accountmanager

Ok, so I have "fully" functional Account application. Except 1 thing.

My application takes data from SQlite DB and create accounts through ContactContract with Account name and type specified like

```
contactsOperations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, static_variables.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, static_variables.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                    .withYieldAllowed(true)
                    .build());
```

And on some phones, almost all(and emulators) in standard contacts application I see that account created and Account place is set to `static_variables.ACCOUNT_NAME` as intended.

But on some devices place is "Unknown"(thought Account is created and exists) and on some contact doesn't visible at all, but exist.

When(on any phone) I check it with

```
Cursor cursor_raw = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I see those contacts in the end with Account name and type setted correctly.

**1. That's a first question, what's wrong?**

Second more not question, but one more evidence for previous. When I go to System->Accounts-> Add account, I see there my Account type and I can create It.

But when I in standartd contacts application and I press add contact, I see "Google", "Exchange", "SIM" and couple more but not mine.
Also in standartd app, when I choosing "Open account settings" (where autosync located) I see same accounts "Google", "Exchange", "SIM" and couple more but not mine.

So second
**2. What Account/ContentProvider/or something else is wrong. Which options in account I don't add, so account isn't visible in all places?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short. Not fully configured SyncAdapter. If you don't want change contentAuthority of ours than just create one more sync adapter with different contentAuthority.

Links to fix the problem.

[Display custom sync adapter as an option when adding contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195584/display-custom-sync-adapter-as-an-option-when-adding-contacts)

[How to add my application's account to the Android Contacts application's "Accounts" list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506861/how-to-add-my-applications-account-to-the-android-contacts-applications-accou)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/android-sdk-support_r11/tests/res/xml